# AngularJS directive using multiple services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

**UPDATE**

My controller loads data from two services, and the directive is linked before one of the services has returned data. So I think I need to find a way to prevent loading the directive until the variable from the second service has actually been populated.

What is the best way to handle that?

**Original question:**

I have a scope with an array of objects, and also a single integer. So, in the controller, something like this:

```
$scope.array = [
    {title: 'foo', first: 'spam', second: 'eggs'}, 
    {title: 'bar', first: 'maps', second: 'sgge'}
];
$scope.another = 400;
```

I am using ngRepeat to pass values from each object in the array to a directive, like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in array" 
     my-directive="a.title" 
     my-first-val="a.first" 
     my-second-val="a.second"></div>
```

I would also like to bind another value, which is the same for all instances of the directive, but may also change:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in array" 
     my-directive="a.title" 
     my-first-val="a.first" 
     my-second-val="a.second"
     another-val="another"></div>
```

This final value never seems to bind properly [actually, it didn't bind because it hadn't populated yet - the syntax used here is fine]. Is this possible? Is there another way to bind a single value to all instances of a directive using ngRepeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your updated question, I suggest you to use a $q promise. You could use a promise for loading the data of each service, and then the `all` method to combine the 2.

```
var promise1 = arrayService.getArray();
var promise2 = anotherService.getAnother();
var promise = $q.all([promise1, promise2]);
promise.then(function(data) {
  $scope.array = data[0];
  $scope.another = data[1];
});
```

EDIT: I understand from your comment that you want to know how to return a promise with a service.
Code in 'arrayService' service

```
angular.module('yourApp').service('arrayService', function($q, someAsyncService) {
  this.getArray = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    someAsyncService.get(function(err, data){
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      }
      else {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like what I need, except I take it from [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3295) that we can't yet do this with services?

Comment: I don't think this pull request is related. You can have your services return promises by using the $q service. I updated my response to show you how you can turn a 'classic' async service (someAsyncService) into a promise-based service (arrayService) using $q.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope, so you're `another` is different in every child scope.
I would try defining `another` as the property of an object:

`$scope.whatever.another = 400`

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in array" 
 my-directive="a.title" 
 my-first-val="a.first" 
 my-second-val="a.second"
 another-val="whatever.another"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my update; the issue is coordinating two services with the rendering of the directive.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use expression evaluation with double braces

```
<div ng-repeat="a in array" 
 my-directive="a.title" 
 my-first-val="a.first" 
 my-second-val="a.second"
 another-val="{{another}}"></div>
```

angular would then try to evaluate the expression from the $scope instead of looking for the another variable from within the child scope created by ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

in response to the updated question one approach you could take if you have access to the directive and can change it is to add a scope.$watch to the another-val attribute in the link or controller function

```
            scope.$watch('anotherVal', function(newVal) {
                //do something here...
            });
```